# How to ask hyperref works only with href

Tags: hyperref, links

How to ask `hyperref` works ONLY with `\url` and `\href` commands?

Comment: You want to use `hyperref` only for `\url` and `\href` commands, but not all other features like PDF bookmarks, section links etc., is it? There is the `url` package for once. Not sure if it also provides `\href`.

Comment: All of your questions have one or several responses that seem to answer them, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 16):

`\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}`

Comment: Thank you! Why I didn't find it in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but does this help:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref} 

    \begin{document}

    Here is a url: \url{http://www.google.com}

    Here is the \href{http://www.google.com}{google site}.
    \end{document}
```